# sending automatic SMS in iOS with Delphi XE8

Tags: ios, delphi, sms, delphi-xe8

Is it possible to send automatic text messages in iOS with Delphi Xe8?
I have found examples to do so in Android, but none in iOS. Would I need to import headers to use in Delphi or is there already built in functionality to do so?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The SMS systems on the two platforms work differently.

On Android it is possible to send an SMS programmatically and entirely automatically.

On iOS (and WinPhone) you can only *pre-compose* an SMS message and then hand over to a system component to have it presented (by the system) to the user for them to confirm whether they wish to send the message or not.

The **iOS** code for this is:

```
var sms := new MFMessageComposeViewController;

sms.messageComposeDelegate := self;
sms.recipients  := ['7275']; // mobile #('s)
sms.body        := 'The message to send';

presentViewController(sms) animated(true) completion(nil);
```

**NOTE:** This code is ObjectPascal, but it is **RemObjects Oxygene**, which compiles *directly* against the Cocoa framework and produces native iOS code, so no need to import headers etc.  To convert this to FireMonkey you will need to find the corresponding declarations/headers in Delphi, assuming they are provided.

When converting to Delphi it might help to compare with the **Objective-C** version of this code, since Delphi provides none of the extended support for the syntax involved in Cocoa framework calls.  For example, setting the **recipients** property in Objective-C:

sms.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"7275", nil];

Further discussion of the differences and how the above Oxygene code corresponds to the Objective-C, to help in the conversion to Delphi, is in [a blog post I wrote about having developed an SMS based application for iOS, Android (and WinPhone)](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/2280).

Answer (score 1):

for ios use dpf ios native controls :)

this is my tested function ( dest number is in object itself ... )

```
procedure SEND_SMS(NUMBER, TEXT: string);
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
   var SmsManager: JSmsManager;
       smsTo, txt: JString;
   begin
      SmsManager := TJSmsManager.JavaClass.getDefault;
      smsTo := StringToJString(NUMBER);
      txt := StringToJString(TEXT) ;
      SmsManager.sendTextMessage( smsTo, nil, txt, nil, nil);
   end;
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF iOS}
   var sms: TDPFMessageCompose;
   begin
   sms := TDPFMessageCompose.Create(application);
   SMS.MessageCompose( TEXT, [NUMBER] ) ;
   sms.free;
  end ;
 {$ENDIF}
 {$IF Defined(MSWINDOWS) }
  begin
    showmessage( 'sms ');
  end;
 {$ENDIF}
```

Comment: please add units required in the uses clause to compile